# Store crash report into file

Tags: swift, macos, xcglogger

I had built a macOS application. When I delivered the app to the client, the app is crashing at some points. So I thought of putting the log file somewhere in the client's system so whenever the app crashed then I will have the exact location where is crashing. I'm using [XCGLogger](https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger) for storing debug logs in the file.

It storing the debug log. But whenever the app is crashing, it's not storing the crash report. I even change the output level to info. but it's not storing the crashing report.

Comment: XCGLogger only logs what you give it, it doesn't handle crash logs by itself.

Comment: Is there is any way to store the crash report? @DaveWood

Comment: You need to handle gathering the crash report. A quick search reveals this project that may help: https://github.com/sbooth/SFBCrashReporter Another example can be found here: https://github.com/Ranchero-Software/NetNewsWire/tree/main/Mac/CrashReporter